# Override community block with local

Tags: magento

Here is code for my local config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Tag>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Custom_Tag>
</modules>
<global>        
    <blocks>
    <tag>
        <class>Custom_Tag_Block</class>
    </tag>
<tag>      
    <rewrite>
        <default>Custom_Tag_Block_Default</default>
    </rewrite>
</tag>
</blocks>

</global>

</config>
```

Here is code for my module file

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Tag>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <SomeExtensionName_TagManager/> 
    </depends>
    </Custom_Tag>
</modules>
</config>
```

Structure of Community extension is 
app/code/community/SomeExtensionNa/TagManager/Block/Default.php

Comment: We need to see `app/code/community/SomeExtensionNa/TagManager/etc/config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tag>      
    <rewrite>
        <all>Custom_Tag_Block_Default</all>
    </rewrite>
</tag>
```

or

```
<tag>      
    <rewrite>
        <popular>Custom_Tag_Block_Default</popular>
    </rewrite>
</tag>
```

Comment: working on frontend or admin.  change the name of your module